# Construction of a biproduct

Tags: category-theory, abelian-categories

In an additive category with finite limits, consider the arrows  $f:A\to  B$ and $g:B\to  A$, such that $f\circ g$ is $1_B$; I  should prove that $A$ is a non trivial binary product. My only idea was to  use  the kernel (that exists because it is a limit) of $f$, call  it  $k:K\to A$, that obviously  satisfies $f\circ k=0$; however I don't know if exists an arrow  $h:A\to  K$ such that $h\circ g=0$ and $h\circ k =1_A$. Is this the right path or I need to think something else? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: consider the endomorphism  $Id-gf\colon A \rightarrow A$, and remember that the $k$ you defined is a monomorphism.